# Instance field is not null but Error: #1009 still exist

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
playBtn: [object MovieClip]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at My_fla::MainTimeline/frame21()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at My_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_5()
```

Comment: We can't know with what you've provided whether the error you are receiving is actually related to `playBtn`.

Comment: A rough guess is this instance field is present on some frames but not all, although it may be referenced on frames it's not present on in actionscript